# Cloning in KVM-Qemu

Tags: clone, linux-kvm

How does kvm clone the qcow2 images? I couldn't find any documentation on the internals of the cloning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If image not active in a VM (Offline migration)

```
rsync -a source.qcow2 destination.qcow2
```

Could be also done with `qemu-img convert ...`.
[Live migration](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Migration) is possilbe aswell.